# Prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x = e$ using sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm aware of the proof of $\lim_{n \to \infty }(1+\frac 1n)^n = e$ using monotone convergence theorem but I want to prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+\frac 1x)^x = e$ using sequential criterion for limits . How I can write it rigorously ?

More precisely : For every $a_n \to \infty$ s.t $a_n \in D_f$ prove $(1+\frac 1{a_n})^{a_n} \to e$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star)$

Comment: @ThePirateBay I got to $\star$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any sequence of real numbers $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $x_n\to +\infty$.

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\right)$$

For sufficiently large $x_n$ as $x_n\to +\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$, e.g. $x_n\ge 1$, we have

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor x_n\rfloor +1}=$$

$$=\left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}\left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}\right)\stackrel{n\to +\infty}\to e\cdot (1+0)=e$$

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\ge \left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor+1}\right)^{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}=$$

$$=\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor + 1}\right)^{\lfloor x_n\rfloor +1}}{1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor+1}}\stackrel{n\to +\infty}\to \frac{e}{1+0}=e$$

By Squeeze Theorem $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)=e$$

$$\lim_{n\to -\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)\stackrel{m=-n}=\lim_{m\to +\infty}\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{-m}\right)=$$

$$=\lim_{m\to +\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{m-1}\right)^{m-1}\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{m-1}\right)\right)=$$

$$=e\cdot (1+0)=e$$

The proof that $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)=e$$ is similar to what I've done before.

Comment: Can you explain why $\left(1+\frac{1}{x_n}\right)^{x_n}\le \left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x_n\rfloor}\right)^{\lfloor x_n\rfloor +1}$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W Because $x_n\ge \lfloor x_n\rfloor$ and $x_n<\lfloor x_n\rfloor + 1$ and $1+\frac{1}{x_n}>1$ (the function $f(x)=a^x$ strictly increases when $a>1$, $x\in\mathbb R$ and obviously the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ strictly decreases when $x>0$) when $x_n$ is large enough (e.g. $x_n\ge 1$) as $x_n\to +\infty$ as $n\to +\infty$. I'm using [the floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences 
$$a_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}$$ 
and 
$$b_{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$
Using **Bernoulli's inequality** you can show that:

1. $a_{n}$ is **monotone increasing** and upper bounded
2. $b_{n}$ is **monotone decreasing** and lower bounded
3. $\underset{n\to\infty }{\lim}{\ a_n}=e$
4. $\underset{n\to\infty }{\lim}{\ b_n}=e$

Finally:

$$a_{n}\leq \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x} \leq b_{n}$$

Comment: We should prove for every $a_n \to \infty$ the sequence $(1+ 1/a_n)^{a_n}$ converges to $e$ .

Comment: @S.H.W: this should be included in your question. It is hard to tell what your question is asking, and I think this comment makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: @robjohn I've added it , thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You can also prove a more general statement:

> Suppose that $\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}{\ (f_{n}-1)g_n}$ exists. If $\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}{\ f_{n}}=1$ and $\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}{\ g_{n}}=\infty$
>
> $$\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}{\ \displaystyle{f_{n}^{g_n}}}=e^{\ \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}{\ (f_{n}-1)g_n}}$$

This is explained in **B.P. Demidovich** book.

Then, using this you can see that:

> If $f$ and $g$ are functions such that
> $$\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ f(x)}=1$$
> $$\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ g(x)}=\infty$$
> the limit bellow exists
> $$\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ (f(x)-1)g(x)}$$
> then
> $$ \underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{\ \underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ (f(x)-1)g(x)}} $$